# can unprotected sexual activity be considered attempt to murder in this section of IPC?

Tags: india, indian-penal-code

IPC 307 states

> Attempt to murder.—Whoever does any act with such intention or knowledge, and under such circumstances that, if he by that act caused death, he would be guilty of murder, shall be punished with imprisonment of either description for a term which may extend to ten years, and shall also be liable to fine; and if hurt is caused to any person by such act, the offender shall be liable either to 1[imprisonment for life], or to such punishment as is hereinbefore mentioned. Attempts by life convicts.—2[When any person offending under this section is under sentence of 1[imprisonment for life], he may, if hurt is caused, be punished with death

since unprotected sexual activity causes diseases like HIV and AIDS also would things like engaging in activities that increase risk of fatal infectious diseases with the intent or knowledge that it might kill someone be covered in this act ? also keep in mind the consent defence isn't possible in offences where death is a possibility

Comment: that'd make it illegal to have sex at all. I seriously doubt that's how you want the law to be interpreted, as it'd inevitably lead to extinction unless the law were changed :) I don't know about India but in the Netherlands there were several cases recently where someone was charged with rape for taking off his condom during sex without consent from the partner (the sex was itself consensual). Some of those led to convictions, some did not. I think similar cases in the US where people deliberately infected others with HIV in similar situations also exist (the Dutch cases didn't involve that).

Comment: Deliberately infecting someone with HIV is certainly a crime, but whether it's murder will need to be determined by the situation. However, just because something _might_ cause harm, it's typically not a crime. Driving cars is not a crime, even though you might kill someone.

Comment: @jwenting Well, such a law would work as well as the prohibition did, I suppose.

Comment: @PMF create a mandatory death sentence for having sex?

Comment: what about my other example ? where someone intentionally and negligently spreads a disease. there's a seperate section for this see ipc 269 but even that seems broad

Comment: @jwenting Well, that would be a good start to save the earth from humanity. In fact, that's pretty close to what the church tried in the early middle ages. Their "ideal" and only way to (eternal) life was asceticism. But they realized that this would kill the church itself, so the mariage was invented (which was still better than random sex origies)

Comment: I think you would have to know you had a fatal sexually-transmitted disease such as HIV. And HIV treatment would have to not have been invented yet (although even after this it might still be some kind of attempted battery). Unprotected sexual activity does *not* cause HIV/AIDS unless one of the participants already has HIV.

Comment: another interesting question is the non-wearing of masks in SARS-2 times.

Comment: @user253751 Today HIV is absolutely not fatal today if treated competently.

Comment: @gnasher729 that is why I specified the treatment must not have been invented yet